# ruby array hash get key by value and value by key

Tags: arrays, ruby, reverse

I have hash`{ "1" => "one", "2" =>  "two", "3"  =>  "three" }`

How to get key by value and value by key.

if I pass "1" I get "one", if I pass "two" I get "2"

```
def finder (string)
  table = { "1" => "one", "2"   =>  "two", "3"  =>  "three" }
  *magick*
  }
  return string
end
puts finder("1") => one
puts finder("one") => 1
```

Comment: table.each {|from,to|
 string.sub!(from,to)
 
 return string

but it works in one way, replaces key by value

Comment: Also it's `{ "1" => "one", "2"    =>  "two", "3"  =>  "three" }` not an array.

Comment: Have you tried to write this function `reversed key and value` ? Can you share actual code?

Comment: ok, updated with function

Comment: @DmitriyK `[...]` is an *array*, whereas `{...}` is a *hash*. Apart from that, what is your expected result?

Comment: puts finder("one") => shoud return "1"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`Hash#key`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-key) returns the key for a given value:

```
@hash = {"1"=>"one", "2"=>"two", "3"=>"three"}
@hash.key("one") #=> "1"
```

or `nil` if no such value exists:

```
@hash.key("four") #=> nil
```

To get either the value for a key, or the key for a value, you could use:

```
def finder(str)
  @hash[str] || @hash.key(str)
end

finder("1")   #=> "one"
finder("one") #=> "1"
```

Comment: puts hash.key("1") => "one"

puts hash.has_value?("one")

I don't know what I pass key or value

Comment: @DmitriyK it wasn't clear to me that you want both. I've updated my answer accordingly. Maybe you should update your question, too :-)

Comment: May you combine with my code, I don't get what's that @hash , new for me

Comment: @DmitriyK `@hash` is an [instance variable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Instance+Variables). I've used it for demonstration purposes, because you can access it from within a method (so I don't have to define the hash twice). Just replace it with `table`.

Comment: Do you know if `key` performs a linear search of keys or if Ruby maintains a hash of values to keys as well as of keys to values?

Comment: @CarySwoveland go to https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-key (the first link in the answer) and click on "click to toggle source" in the top right corner of the documentation while hovering with your mouse. You'll see how it is implemented.

Answer (score 4):

If your hash is large and you will be doing this repeatedly, you could create a new hash for speedy lookups:

```
h = {"1"=>"one", "2"=>"two", "3"=>"three"}
nh = h.merge h.invert
  #=> {"1"=>"one", "2"=>"two", "3"=>"three", "one"=>"1", "two"=>"2", "three"=>"3"}
```